# When is $T$-Alg monoidal closed?

Tags: category-theory

Given a category $\mathcal{V}$ and a monad $(T,\eta,\mu)$, what would be the sufficient conditions on $\mathcal{V}$ and $T$, for the category of $T$ algebras to be monoidal closed?

(I'm pretty sure that Kock proved that, if $T$ has strength and is commutative, then $T$-alg is closed; can we relax that condition, or change it in anyway?)

Comment: Yes, that is the theorem of Kock. Why are you seeking different conditions?

Comment: Well I have a cartesian (but not closed) category as $\mathcal{V}$ and a strong (but not commutative) monad, and have a strong suspicion that the $T$-Alg should be closed monoidal (as in the case of abelian groups) -- I was hoping that there exists some general argument. (Although I just found some work by Hyland and Powers that I might be able to use http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(02)00133-0 )

Comment: I don't see any reason why the algebras would be closed if the base isn't closed. After all, the hom module between two modules is a subset of the hom set... Not to mention, the identity monad is the nicest possible monad there is, so if its algebras are closed, then the base is already closed!

Comment: (Also, the abelian group monad is commutative.)

Comment: Abelian group monad is commutative wrt tensor product and not with cartesian product, no? And if I understand things correctly algebras over the abelian monad in pSet will produce a closed category, even though the monad has nothing to do with the smash product of pSet (or is it commutative with the smash product? I plead ignorance in this case).

Comment: Every monad on sets has a unique strength and being a commutative monad is a property of that strength. The tensor product of abelian groups doesn't come into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need that $\mathcal{V}$ is closed monoidal, $T$ is a monoidal monad and that certain coequalizers in $\mathcal{V}$ exist which commute with $T$. For details, see [Tensors, monads and actions](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0101v3.pdf) by Gavin Seal.

Comment: It is not necessary to assume that the coequalisers _commute_ with $T$, but some condition about existence of coequalisers and preservation of epimorphisms seems to be required.

Comment: I know that, but I wanted to keep it short.